# Codeigniter4 htaccess file wont work with options all - indexes

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-4

i want to setup a new codeigniter4 project.

I've upload all files into [www.mydomain.com/sub1/sub2](http://www.mydomain.com/sub1/sub2)

The htaccess files into [www.mydomain.com/sub1/sub2/public](http://www.mydomain.com/sub1/sub2/public) makes some trouble.

If i use the default file, i always get a `"500 Internal Error"`

So i check line by line. so i figure out that the line `"Options All -Indexes"` produce this error. If i delete it, i see the welcome page. But i think there is a reason why i should add this and related to this `"Options +FollowSymlinks"` too.

What can caused this problem. In my codeigniter3 projects i use

```
"DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes"
```

and it works fine. Codeigniter4 seems to need it into another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of testing and trieing, i find a way (but i not really understand why).

Changing the htacess file in the public folder
from

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

to this

```
Options -Indexes
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

solved the problem and the codeigniter project is viewable. So maybe it could help someone.